# What is kdeconnectd and how to permanently disallow it in the firewall?

Tags: kde, firewall, ufw

What is kdeconnectd and how can I permanently prohibit it from connecting to the Internet?

In the gufw firewall it shows up under "Report" where I clicked the + button after selecting it and selected "Deny" and clicked "Close". Later it was set back to "Allow" apparently. Why is that? Is kdeconnectd needed for anything that I need?
Is it enough to add a new rule that denies it access to the Internet? Why isn't it enough to simply select "Deny" in the listbox? Should I add a rule for everything under "Report" which I'd like to deny Internet-access (by clicking "Add" instead of "Close")? (Which is simply *everything* until I actually need it and *explicitly allow* it!)

I'm using Debian 9.1 with KDE.

Not sure if this is related: [High CPU load (kded5, plasmashell, dbus-daemon)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/382382/high-cpu-load-kded5-plasmashell-dbus-daemon) (still unsolved).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how to block it, but kdeconnectd is a daemon of KDE Connect, a program used to communicate between a Linux computer and an Android smartphone on your local network. If you don't use KDE Connect, you might as well remove it.

Comment: I use it but would like to have it not running except when I started it. I blocked it by DROPing all incoming and outgoing traffic by default via iptables.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to prevent it from starting like this: `rm /etc/xdg/autostart/org.kde.kdeconnect.daemon.desktop`